Fix "Non-monotonic DTS" Warning Caused By asetnsamples Filter
I'm using the following complex filter to mute certain parts of an audio file and replace those parts with a beep generated by the sine filter:
[0]asetnsamples=n=1,volume=0:enable='between(t,1.57,1.97)+between(t,4.77,5.27)+between(t,5.37,5.87)+between(t,6.37,6.77)'[dippedVocals];sine=d=10:f=1000:samples_per_frame=1,pan=stereo|FL=c0|FR=c0[constantBleep];[constantBleep]atrim=start=0:end=6.77[shortenedBleep];[shortenedBleep]volume=0:enable='between(t,0,1.57)+between(t,1.97,4.77)+between(t,5.27,5.37)+between(t,5.87,6.37)'[dippedBleep];[dippedVocals][dippedBleep]amix=inputs=2

Since I need the locations specified to be exact I'm using the asetnsamples filter to set 1 sample per frame to get the highest possible accuracy.  However, as soon as I add this asetnsamples filter to my filter chain I get thousands of these messages:
Non-monotonic DTS; previous: XXX, current: XXX; changing to XXX.  This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

Any idea what's causing that and how to fix it?  BTW, the input file is a ogg file encoded at 44100Hz and the output file is a wav file.  Do wav files even contain timestamps?

This suggests the source file has gaps in its timestamps. Add asetpts=N/SR/TB before the asetnsamples but check for sync in the output.

Nope they don't have timestamps.  Convert the .ogg to .wav first, then run the filter on the wav file.
